# How do Multiple Multi-Class Feats work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, class-feature

I am wondering if I took 2 multiclassing feats, could they

a) effect a class ability given by a class other then the one the feat is made for (Having wildshape ability but getting it from Ranger instead of Druid).

b) the level adjustments stack for other abilities

(Both feats figure out level for skirmish damage by adding the level of Scout to Ranger or Druid. Would I figure out skirmish as a level 14 scout (Adding Scout and Ranger levels, due to being highest); level 15 (Adding Scout, Ranger, and Druid Levels); or level 23 scout (Adding Scout and Ranger Levels, plus Scout and Druid levels)).

The example is as follows:

- Classes

  - Scout 8
  - [UA Variant Ranger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#ranger) 6 (Gives Wild Shape)
  - [UA Variant Druid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#druid) 1 (Loses Wild Shape for monk and ranger abilities)
- Feats (I meet the pre-req for each)

  - Swift Avenger
    Add your Druid level to your Scout level to determine

    1. your Skirmish damage and AC bonus; &
    2. how many uses of Wild Shape you get each day.
  - Swift Hunter
    Add your Ranger and Scout levels together to determine the value of your Skirmish bonuses –and- your effective Ranger level for determining the number and value of your Favored Enemies. In addition, your Skirmish bonus damage applies to your Favored Enemies even if it is normally immune to such damage.

Comment: Which variant druid do you mean? [This one, that gets monk and ranger features](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#ranger)?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't realize there was 2 variant classes for Druid in UA. The one I was meaning was on page 58, not Druidic Avenger.

The variant I mean Gain: Bonus to Armor Class when unarmored (as monk, including Wisdom bonus to AC), fast movement (as monk), favored enemy (as ranger), swift tracker (as ranger), Track feat (as ranger).
Lose: Armor and shield proficiency, wild shape (all versions).

Answer (score 1):

#### Wild Shape

I would personally rule that, for the purposes of Swift Avenger, you use your ranger levels instead of your druid levels. After all, ranger is the class that actually grants wild shape, while druid does not. So I would rule that you have the wild shape of a 14th-level druid (from scout 8/ranger 6 and Swift Avenger), and that this would still be limited to Small or Medium animals, per variant ranger.

The rules do not indicate that this happens, however. Strictly speaking, your level of druid would stack with scout for wild shape even though it doesn’t have wild shape, because that’s what Swift Avenger says happens. On the other hand, levels of ranger would be separate, so that you have two instances of wild shape: one as a 9th-level druid (scout + druid + Swift Avenger) and another as a 6th-level druid (Small or Medium animals only, from variant ranger).

#### Skirmish and Favored Enemy

This case is simpler: ranger and scout stack together, so you have the skirmish of a 14th-level scout and the favored enemies of a 14th-level ranger.

Your druid level also grants a favored enemy, thanks to the variant. It does not stack with your scout or ranger levels for either purpose, however. It just means you have one more favored enemy than you would have as a 14th-level ranger (and consequently, your highest favored enemy bonus is +2 higher than it otherwise would be).